# Installing Tensorflow for Keras: cloud-init missing parts

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras

**Setup**: This is all done using an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance.

1. Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type
2. RStudio Server

**What I've tried**: I am trying to install the `keras` package in `R` with `tensorflow`. The `keras` package installs with no problem. The problem is when I run `install_keras()`:

`> keras::install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu")`

```
Using existing virtualenv at  ~/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow 
Upgrading pip ...
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/a1/0d452b6901b0157a0134fd27ba89bf95a857fbda64ba52e1ca2cf61d8412/pip-10.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires argparse, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires cheetah, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires oauth, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires PrettyTable, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires pyserial, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-10.0.0
Upgrading wheel ...
Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/d2/22cde5ea9af055f81814f9f2545f5ed8a053eb749c08d186b369959189a8/wheel-0.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires argparse, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires cheetah, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires oauth, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires PrettyTable, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires pyserial, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.31.0
Upgrading setuptools ...
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires argparse, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires cheetah, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires oauth, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires PrettyTable, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires pyserial, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-39.0.1
Installing TensorFlow ...
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a1/ce/5bada74b1de0cfaafcc982291230ee987a769ace8ed9dedb36dbfe1bffc0/tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting h5py
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/9e/d68bd01058e748bd5e7c3c6368d1703b4cd882b669e5d993a0237c75af5a/h5py-2.7.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyyaml
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919d9c0c085fd2b3775fd3eca826012bef76d8c/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/49/a0483e7308b4b04b5a898789911dbb876d9fea54e7df0453915e47744cfd/Pillow-5.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting keras
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/65/e4aff762b8696ec0626a6654b1e73b396fcc8b7cc6b98d78a1bc53b85b48/Keras-2.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/0b/5deb712a9ea5bb0a1de837d04ef7625c5f3ee44efe7ed0765ceda681d7f1/scipy-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34>=1.1.6 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/db/e56e6b4bbac7c4a06de1c50de6fe1ef3810018ae11732a50f15f62c7d050/enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/4d/418dda252cf92bad00ab82d6b2a856e7843b47a5c2f084aed34b14b67d64/numpy-1.14.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/91/cc9805f1ff7b49f620136b3a7ca26f6a1be2ed424606804b0fbcf499f712/astor-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/54/b647a6323be6526be27b2c90bb042769f1a7a6e59bd1a5f2eeb795bfece4/grpcio-1.11.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting mock>=2.0.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/35/f187bdf23be87092bd0f1200d43d23076cee4d0dec109f195173fd3ebc79/mock-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.4.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/61/54c3a9cfde6ffe0ca6a1786ddb8874263f4ca32e7693ad383bd8cf935015/protobuf-3.5.2.post1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting tensorboard<1.8.0,>=1.7.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/5b/18f50b69b8af42f93c47cd8bf53337347bc1974480a10de51fdd7f8fd48b/tensorboard-1.7.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/d2/22cde5ea9af055f81814f9f2545f5ed8a053eb749c08d186b369959189a8/wheel-0.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting backports.weakref>=1.0rc1 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/ec/f598b633c3d5ffe267aaada57d961c94fdfa183c5c3ebda2b6d151943db6/backports.weakref-1.0.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/cc/6dd9a3869f15c2edfab863b992838277279ce92663d334df9ecf5106f5c6/idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/cb/6965947c13a94236f6d4b8223e21beb4d576dc72e8130bd7880f600839b8/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting futures>=2.2.0 (from grpcio>=1.8.6->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/99/b2c4e9d5a30f6471e410a146232b4118e697fa3ffc06d6a65efde84debd0/futures-3.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/cb/f5be453359271714c01b9bd06126eaf2e368f1fddfff30818754b5ac2328/funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pbr>=0.11 (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/ba/f95e3ec83f93919b1437028e989cf3fa5ff4f5cae4a1f62255f71deddb5b/pbr-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.4.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorboard<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/7d/488b90f470b96531a3f5788cf12a93332f543dbab13c423a5e7ce96a0493/Markdown-2.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting bleach==1.5.0 (from tensorboard<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/70/86c5fec937ea4964184d4d6c4f0b9551564f821e1c3575907639036d9b90/bleach-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html5lib==0.9999999 (from tensorboard<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->tensorflow-gpu)
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires argparse, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires cheetah, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires oauth, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires PrettyTable, which is not installed.
cloud-init 0.7.6 requires pyserial, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: six, enum34, numpy, termcolor, astor, setuptools, protobuf, futures, grpcio, funcsigs, pbr, mock, gast, werkzeug, markdown, wheel, html5lib, bleach, tensorboard, absl-py, backports.weakref, tensorflow-gpu, h5py, pyyaml, idna, urllib3, certifi, chardet, requests, Pillow, scipy, keras
Successfully installed Pillow-5.1.0 absl-py-0.2.0 astor-0.6.2 backports.weakref-1.0.post1 bleach-1.5.0 certifi-2018.4.16 chardet-3.0.4 enum34-1.1.6 funcsigs-1.0.2 futures-3.2.0 gast-0.2.0 grpcio-1.11.0 h5py-2.7.1 html5lib-0.9999999 idna-2.6 keras-2.1.5 markdown-2.6.11 mock-2.0.0 numpy-1.14.2 pbr-4.0.2 protobuf-3.5.2.post1 pyyaml-3.12 requests-2.18.4 scipy-1.0.1 setuptools-39.0.1 six-1.11.0 tensorboard-1.7.0 tensorflow-gpu-1.7.0 termcolor-1.1.0 urllib3-1.22 werkzeug-0.14.1 wheel-0.31.0

Installation complete.
```

I've also tried installing `python-argparse`, `python-cheetah` using the command `sudo yum install ...`, and some of them are valid packages, but I still have the error appearing. Is there an environment variable I need to set to know where to look? Did I even install the right packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, 
   try 'sudo pip install (what's missing,ex:argparse)'

Worked for me, hope this helps :)